# Brainstorming: why comparing a memory address with a small integer

Tags: objective-c, assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

Background:  I'm reversing an Obj-C  instance method belonging to a certain class. Here is the interface of the class

```
@interface myClass : NSObject
    { 
            // aStructure contains a lot of function pointers

         struct aStructure **_myStruct;     // ivar offset: 0x14  
         int                             _integer;             // ivar offset: 0x20
    }

   - (void)aMethod;

@end
```

Problem:

Here is a snippet of `aMethod` disassembly

```
[0x0]      mov   edi,    [ebp+arg_0]     ## put self into edi
[0x2]      mov   edx,   [edi+20h]        ## put  self._integer into edi
[0x3]      cmp   edx,   1
[0x4]      jl       end_of_method       ## if (self._integer < 1) return;
[0x5]      lea     eax,   [edx-0Ch]       ## put &self._myStruct into eax
[0x6]      cmp   eax,   3
[0x7]      ja      end_of_method       ## if (&self._myStruct > 3) return;
// other stuff
```

The 6th line shows a comparaison between a memory address (`&self._myStruct`) with `3`.

Question: why would you compare a memory address with an int ? It doesn't make much sense for me, since a memory address will be always > 3, and thus the method will always exit in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lea     eax,   [edx-0Ch]` simply means `eax = edx - 12`. That the instruction is called "load effective address" doesn't mean it's the only thing it can be used for - compilers often output `lea` instead of `add`/`sub`/`mul` when that instruction is the shorter/faster way of doing a calculation.

The whole snippet checks if `_integer` is between 1 and 15. It stores `_integer - 12` in `eax`, presumably because it will be used later in the method.

Comment: In general, is there a way to identify whether it's an arithmetic calculation or a real effective address loading ? Do you just check the next instructions to see if it's logical ?

Comment: Yeah, the only way is to check if the result of the calculation is used as an address later.

Comment: Oh I understood, i thought `lea eax, [edx-0ch]` meant `lea eax, [edi+20h-0Ch]`  whereas it is `lea eax, [value_of_self._integer-0Ch]`. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

`self._integer` is loaded into `edx` on line 2. and it remains there until line 5.

On line 5 you assign `eax` to the sum of `edx` (`self._integer`) and -0xC. So, you end up comparing `self._integer`-0xC with 3 on line 6. There's no address comparison anywhere, unless the presented disassembly is incomplete or incorrect.

The `lea` instruction, which was originally intended for address arithmetic, can be used for other purposes as well as we're seeing here.